# How does this algorithm for the Van der Corput sequence work?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algorithms, binary, equidistribution

For any natural number $n$ write its binary expansion as $n = \sum_{i=0}^{k(n)} n_i 2^i$. Then the $n$th entry of the binary [Van der Corput sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Corput_sequence) is defined to be the dyadic rational

$$V(n) = \sum_{i=0} ^{k(n)} n_i 2^{-i-1}.$$

In words, $V(n)$ are the binary integers, reflected across the decimal point. The first few binary numbers are $$1,10,11,100,101,110,111,1000,1001,1010,1011,\dots$$
and correspondingly the first few entries of $V(n)$ are (in binary)
$$ 0.1, 0.01, 0.11, 0.001, 0.101, 0.011, 0.111,0.0001,0.1001,0.0101,0.1101,\dots$$
or equivalently
$$ \frac12, \frac14, \frac34,\frac18,\frac58,\frac38,\frac78,\frac1{16},\frac7{16},\frac5{16},\frac{13}{16},\dots$$

Apparently, this algorithm from [the Wikipedia page for Halton sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halton_sequence) (a generalisation of $V$) computes the sequence $V(n)$:

```
def halton_sequence(b):
    """Generator function for Halton sequence."""
    n, d = 0, 1
    while True:
        x = d - n
        if x == 1:
            n = 1
            d *= b
        else:
            y = d // b
            while x <= y:
                y //= b
            n = (b + 1) * y - x
        yield n / d
```

I'm trying to understand this algorithm. Clearly, $n$ and $d$ denote the numerator and denominator, and $x=d-n>0$.

If $x=1$ i.e. $n/d = (b^{k}-1)/b^{k}$ then we need to increment the power of the denominator to get $1/b^{k+1}$; this is clear.

In the remaining case, we leave the denominator as is and focus on the next numerator. The number $y$ is the largest power of $b$ that is strictly smaller than $x=d-n$. Then, the next numerator is claimed to be $ n_{new} = (b+1) y - x = (b+1)y - d + n.$
In summary my pseudocode for the algorithm is:

1. given $(n, d)$ (initialised with $n=0,d=1$)
2. if $n = d-1$ then return $(1, db)$ else
3. define $y = \max_{k \ge 0} \{ b^k : n + b^k < d \}$
4. return $( (b+1)y - d + n, d)$

### **Q:** How do I link this back to the original definition of $V(n)$?

I have checked the paper (Berblinger, Michael; Schlier, Christoph (1991). "Monte Carlo integration with quasi-random numbers: some experience". Computer Physics Communications. 66 (2–3): 157–166. doi:10.1016/0010-4655(91)90064-R. ISSN 0010-4655.) where this algorithm originates but did not find any clarifying remarks.

From steps 3 and 4, it seems the quantity $y-d+n \in [-d,0)$ could be useful. I've computed the first few iterations of $(n,d;y-d+n)$ for $b=2$. In the case when $n=d-1$ I fill the $y-d+n$ value with the symbol $X$ instead:
$$
\text{init with }(0,1) \to (1,2; X) \to (1,4;X) \to (3,4;-1) \to (1,8;X) \to (5,8;-3) \to (3,8;-1) \to (7,8;-1) \to (1,16;X)
$$
Its not so easy to search for this sequence on Math.SE; one other post on this sequence is [Why is the formula for generating Van der Corput sequences called an Inverse Radical Function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/849848/why-is-the-formula-for-generating-van-der-corput-sequences-called-an-inverse-rad)

Comment: `halton_sequence(2)` [yields](https://stackoverflow.com/q/231767) the sequence's elements as floats. Once the sequence index gains a binary digit, the denominator doubles viz. `d *= b`. This is detected by `x==1`, presumably exploiting $2^n-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}2^k=1$.

Comment: @J.G. yeah, that much was clear to me but I noticed a typo thanks to your comment so thank you. Not sure about the use of the sum since the algorithm is the same for any base, but will think about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm works as follows:

1. We always have $d$ a power of $b$, $d=b^D$, say, and $0\le n< b^D$.  So, write $n$ as a sequence of $D$ base-$b$ digits.
2. If $n$'s digits all equal $b-1$, $n=(b-1)\cdots (b-1)$, then we have exhausted all possible digit sequences of length $D$ and need to increase $D$.  Then, $n=b^D-1$.  Since this is equivalent to $x=d-n=b^D-(b^D-1)=1$, the test `if x == 1` checks for this.
3. In this case, we multiply $d$ by $b$, meaning that we increase $D$ by 1, and set $n$ to $0\cdots01$ to start making digit sequences of length $D+1$.
4. Otherwise, we need to increment $n$.  To do this, we need to find the leftmost digit of $n$ which is not $b-1$.
5. This is done by the loop on the variable $y$, which is a power of $b$, $b^i$, say, corresponding to a digit position in $n$. Since $x=d-n$, the test `x <= y` is equivalent to testing whether $d\le n + y$, i.e., whether $n\ge b^D - b^i$.  Since $b^D-b^i$ has the base-$b$ expansion $(b-1)\cdots(b-1)0\cdots 0$,
   this will be true just when the digit positions in $n$ which correspond to $y$ or are to the left of $y$ all contain the digit $b-1$.
6. When we exit the `while` loop, we have found a digit which is not $b-1$.  We must increment the digit, which we can do by adding $y=b^i$ to $n$, and clear the digits $b-1$ to the left of the digit, which we can do by adding $by=b^{i+1}$ to $n$.  Clearing the digits $b-1$ will cause an overflow carry out of the leftmost digit of $n$, which we can remove by subtracting $d=b^D$ from $n$.
7. Therefore, we need to add $(b+1)y-d$ to $n$.  Since $x=d-n$, this can be done by the assignment statement `n = (b + 1) * y - x`.
8. Finally, in both cases, we yield the generated value.

Comment: +1 On a glance this looks great, I will have a closer look soon!

Comment: OK, I agree with this answer. Thanks! Although in step 4, its not really $n$ that you increment but instead the digit-reversed version of $n$